# Echo each key value from array if second array key equals

Tags: php, arrays, function, compare, exists

I have two arrays:

```
$choices = array  (
        [model] => 3D Modeling / BIM
        [edb] => Engineering & Design-Build
        [gse] => Green & Sustainable Energy
        [ipd] => Integrated Project Design
        [lc] => Lean Construction
        [mt] => Material Supply
        [ecs] => Electrical Construction & Service
        [fps] => Fire Protection Services
        [hms] => HVAC & Mechanical Service
        [tsl] => Traffic Signal & Lighting
    )
$servicesSelected = array (
        [model] => 0
        [ipd] => 1
        [lc] => 2
        [mt] => 3
    )
```

I am attempting to check if any array 2 keys equals array 1 keys and print the value from array 1 if that key equals the array 2 key. I'm not entirely sure where to start. But in the example I would echo the following because their keey exists in the comparison.

- 3D Modleling / BIM
- Integrated Project Design
- Lean Contruction
- Material Supply

Comment: bruteforce: a plain loop... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
$choices = array  (
'model' => ' 3D Modeling / BIM',
'edb' => ' Engineering & Design-Build',
'gse' => ' Green & Sustainable Energy',
'ipd' => ' Integrated Project Design',
'lc' => ' Lean Construction',
'mt' => ' Material Supply',
'ecs' => ' Electrical Construction & Service',
'fps' => ' Fire Protection Services',
'hms' => ' HVAC & Mechanical Service',
'tsl' => ' Traffic Signal & Lighting');
$servicesSelected = array (
'model' => 0,
'ipd' => 1,
'lc' => 2,
'mt' => 3);

$printArray = array_intersect_key($choices , $servicesSelected );

var_export($printArray);
?>
```

### Result

```
array (
  'model' => ' 3D Modeling / BIM',
  'ipd' => ' Integrated Project Design',
  'lc' => ' Lean Construction',
  'mt' => ' Material Supply',
)
```

Comment: Awesome!! I was on the right track, got turned around with some other php functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
foreach($servicesSelected as $key2=>$serviceSelected)
  foreach($choices as $key1=>$choice)
    if($key1==$key2) echo $choice;
```